# Code pattern for sequence of tasks

Tags: events, design-patterns, sequence

I have a method which will be required to run a sequence of tasks.

E.g. `ValidateData`, `UploadToCloud`, `SaveToDatabase`, etc.

But they are all sequential and dependent of the previous tasks completed successfully.

I can code them all in procedural methods. But is there any elegant way to organize this?

Comment: There is a design pattern call ActiveRecord is an approach to reading data from a database. Attributes of a table or view are encapsulated within a class. Thus, the object, the instance of the class, is linked to a tuple of the base. After instantiating an object, a new tuple is added to the database at the time of registration. Each object retrieves its data from the database; when an object is updated, the tuple to which it is bound is also updated. The class implements accessors for each attribute.

Comment: The events are not database related.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap it up into `facade` pattern

or use `chain of responsibility` pattern.

But also you can follow KISS and don't over-engineering - if it is super simple case).

Answer (score 0):

I had a read of Facade pattern, it is probably not what I need.

From my understanding, it wraps all the operations in a method, so you can simply perform all the tasks with one method, instead of calling every single method each time.

Whereas my problem is dependent on each task's success to proceed to the next method.

eg. Bank Loan Application.

- check applicant's details is valid ---> proceed to check Account Balance otherwise fail.
- check Account Balance ---> success --> proceed to evaluate property's valuation otherwise fail.
- check Property's valuation --> success --> Grant home loan, otherwise fail.